# Reload part of the page and change URL example explanation

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

To get straight to the point, I need something like this:
[example page](http://www.sodikart.com/en-gb/second-hand-karts/factory/).

When you click on "KARTS", and then i.e, "Rental", the URL changes (and is usable, meaning you can send it tome someone and the same page will open), and the whole page besides the header gets refreshed.

Now, I am not sure whether or not here **actually only the part** of the page gets reloaded (using AJAX/jQuery), or this is a completely new View, with different JSP behind it.
(lets say this is Spring MVC)?

I need a similar thing in my application, except that for me the URL should change when the user enters something in a text input, and hits button Go!
(Instead of just clicking the button as is on this page).

So the question is: Is this AJAX or just a new view with the same header so it only **appears** that only part of the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like new view, same header.

This seems relevent for you though if you're interested: [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)